# How do I have user input Python?

Tags: python

I want to have a program that can take user input (such as the `input(__prompt__)` code) and execute it as if it were part of the actual code.

Example:

Python: What code would you like to run?
User: print('Hello world')
Python: Hello world

I don't even know if this is possible or not but it would really be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Use `exec()`. However, if this project is using sensitive information, be warned that a user can access anything with this script.

```
exec(input(">>> "))
```

Comment: Yes it does thx